# npm install not being running on building container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have a simple node app with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /home/my-app

COPY package.json .
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./server.js ./

RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install \
    npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
```

When I build the image with: `docker build -t my-app:latest .`, I attempt to run the app and it complains that some modules are missing.

When I go into the container via `docker run -i -t my-app:latest /bin/sh` I can see that the packages have not been installed. After manually running `npm install` in the container, it seems to work.

I can only conclude that from this `RUN npm install` not being executed correctly inside the container.

Comment: You're missing an "&&" after npm install or you can add a semicolon ';'

Comment: Wow, 2 hours wasted on this and all I need was a `;`. Makes me feel silly, but nonetheless that worked. Thanks!

Comment: that happens ;)

Comment: Instead of `RUN rm -rf node_modules` you might want to create a `.dockerignore` file.